# Is there a way to calculate this integral without using any special integration techniques? (Feynman's...)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$F(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t^2}e^{-1/t^2}dt\quad(x>0)$

I tried $u$ sub and integration by parts but it's futile.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) **show your attempts** (not just allude to them) and

[format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title, include your question in the body of your post, and correct the misprint (dx should be dt)

Comment: If you substitute $\frac1t=x$, you will need the [error function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: If you integrate dx, the function is a constant and the result is straightforward. I guess dt is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given, $$F(x)=\int_x^1\dfrac{1}{t^2}e^{-1/t^2}dt$$
We can substitute $u=\dfrac{1}{t}\implies du=-\dfrac{1}{t^2}dt$
So, $$F(x)=-\int_{1/x}^1e^{-u^2}du=\int_1^{1/x}e^{-u^2}du$$
This function can be expressed using the [Error Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).
$$\operatorname{erf}(x)=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$
Hence, $$F(x)=\int_0^{1/x}e^{-u^2}du-\int_0^1e^{-u^2}du=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\operatorname{erf}(1)\right)$$
$$\boxed{F(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\operatorname{erf}(1)\right)}$$